# Результат PDO

Tags: pdo, php

Ребят, давно хотел спросить. в общем при работе с запросами через нативную функцию `mysql_query`, можно было проверить прошел запрос ли нет таким образом:

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if($res){}else{}
```

Все было прекрасно. Но вот в `PDO` ситуация немного другая -пр такой проверке `$res` будет всегда `true`, даже если запрос не прошел. Вот интересно кто как проверяет запрос. Я вот проверяю так, но не знаю на сколько это правильно :

```
if($connect -> lastInsertId()){}else{}
```

Answer (score 2):

Никак не надо проверять.

`if($res){}else{}` - это каменный век.
Если подумать, то результат запроса будет отрицательный только в случае, если произошла ошибка в БД. В этом случае надо сообщить об ошибке и завершить работу - то, что писалось раньше в `else`. Ну так PDO умеет сообщить об ошибке и завершить работу без всяких проверок. Все что нужно - это установить режим выброса исключений.

Answer (score 1):

Так

```
if ($query = $pdo->execute($params))
{
  // запрос выполнен успешно
}
else
{
  // запрос не выполнен
}
```